# Is there a more consistent way to declare Bash variables and functions?

Tags: bash, shell

I constantly fight with the decision of how to declare a variable or function in Bash.

Given the following assumptions:

1. Bash is the only scripting language available.
2. Naming conventions are irrelevant.

In the case of *global* variables should I use:

1. `foo=bar` - inside and outside of functions?
2. `declare -g foo=bar` - inside and outside of functions?
3. `local -g foo=bar` - inside of functions?

In the case of *local* variables should I use:

1. `local foo=bar`
2. `declare foo=bar`

In the case of *read-only* variables should I use:

1. `declare -r foo=bar`
2. `local -r foo=bar`
3. `readonly foo` - following [1.] or [2.] without the `-r` flag on the next line.

In the case of functions should I use:

1. `foo() { echo bar; }`
2. `foo { echo bar; }`
3. `function foo() { echo bar; }`
4. `function foo { echo bar; }`

Comment: For functions, option 1 is arguably best as it matches POSIX shell.  If portability isn't a concern, then any of the function conventions can be used; consistency is more important than the details of which option (but I'd probably go with option 1, even so).

Comment: is function option #2 even valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to forget about it I define the following near the top of my `.bashrc` as well as each of my Bash shell script files:

```
# Allow to define an alias.
#
shopt -s expand_aliases

# Defines a function given a name, empty parentheses and a block of commands enclosed in braces.
#
# @param name the name of the function.
# @param parentheses the empty parentheses. (optional)
# @param commands the block of commands enclosed in braces.
# @return 0 on success, n != 0 on failure.
#
alias def=function

# Defines a value, i.e. read-only variable, given options, a name and an assignment of the form =value.
#
# Viable options:
#   * -i - defines an integer value.
#   * -a - defines an array value with integers as keys.
#   * -A - defines an array value with strings as keys.
#
# @param options the options. (optional)
# @param name the name of the value.
# @param assignment the equals sign followed by the value.
# @return 0 on success, n != 0 on failure.
#
alias val="declare -r"

# Defines a variable given options, a name and an assignment of the form =value.
#
# Viable options:
#   * -i - defines an integer variable.
#   * -a - defines an array variable with integers as keys.
#   * -A - defines an array variable with strings as keys.
#
# @param options the options. (optional)
# @param name the name of the variable.
# @param assignment the equals sign followed by the value. (optional)
# @return 0 on success, n != 0 on failure.
#
alias var=declare

# Declares a function as final, i.e. read-only, given a name.
#
# @param name the name of the function.
# @return 0 on success, n != 0 on failure.
#
alias final="readonly -f"
```

The above definitions allow me to say for example:

1. `def foo { echo bar; }`.
2. `final foo`
3. `var foo=bar`
4. `val foo=bar`

As indicated by the comments you can mix and match various variable flags such as `var -g foo=bar` for a global (-g) variable (var) or `val -Ai foobar=([foo]=0 [bar]=1)` for a read-only (val), associative array (-A) consisting of integer (-i) values.

Implicit variable scoping too comes with this approach. Also the newly introduced keywords `def`, `val`, `var` and `final` should be familiar to any software engineer who programs in languages such as JavaScript, Java, Scala and the like.

Comment: I would have thought that conventions for bash scripting should be familiar to software engineers who program in bash, and are therefore used to bash's existing builtins. But then bash does tend to be a bit of a wild west programming environment, so Whatever Works For You as long as you Keep It Away From Me(sm).

Comment: I can't really recommend attempts to emulate one language in another language. Stuff like that is likely to break in unexpected places, because there usually are subtle differences between how instructions behave in one language and the other. It's also likely to confuse whoever inherits the stuff from the previous maintainer.

Comment: I don't attempt to emulate some other programming language but try to embody my decisions not only in coding guidelines but in the code itself. Given any more complex construct than an alias especially when it is undocumented I totally agree that it is only a question of time when things will break.